# Detecting if two images are visually identical

Tags: algorithm, image, image-processing, hash

Sometimes two image files may be different on a file level, but a human would consider them perceptively identical. Given that, now suppose you have a huge database of images, and you wish to know if a human would think some image X is present in the database or not. If all images had a perceptive hash / fingerprint, then one could hash image X and it would be a simple matter to see if it is in the database or not.

I know there is research around this issue, and some algorithms exist, but is there any tool, like a UNIX command line tool or a library I could use to compute such a hash without implementing some algorithm from scratch?

edit: relevant code from findimagedupes, using ImageMagick

```
try $image->Sample("160x160!");
try $image->Modulate(saturation=>-100);
try $image->Blur(radius=>3,sigma=>99);
try $image->Normalize();
try $image->Equalize();
try $image->Sample("16x16");
try $image->Threshold();
try $image->Set(magick=>'mono');
($blob) = $image->ImageToBlob();
```

edit: **Warning!** ImageMagick $image object seems to contain information about the creation time of an image file that was read in. This means that the blob you get will be different even for the same image, if it was retrieved at a different time. To make sure the fingerprint stays the same, use $image->getImageSignature() as the last step.

Comment: That procedure sounds extremely processor intensive.

Comment: *This means that the blob you get will be different even for the same image, if it was retrieved at a different time.* This is not true for the `"$blob"` string (if put into double quotes), that will be the exact same 32 bytes if the image pixels are the same.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[findimagedupes](http://www.jhnc.org/findimagedupes/) is pretty good. You can run "findimagedupes -v fingerprint images" to let it print "perceptive hash", for example.

Comment: Exactly the same algorithm implemented in Python (with GraphicsMagick doing the heavy lifting) here: https://github.com/pts/pyfindimagedupes

Answer (score 5):

Cross-correlation or phase correlation will tell you if the images are the same, even with noise, degradation, and horizontal or vertical offsets.  Using the FFT-based methods will make it much faster than the algorithm described in the question.

The usual algorithm doesn't work for images that are not the same scale or rotation, though.  You could pre-rotate or pre-scale them, but that's really processor intensive.  Apparently you can also do the correlation in a log-polar space and it will be invariant to rotation, translation, and scale, but I don't know the details well enough to explain that.

MATLAB example: [Registering an Image Using Normalized Cross-Correlation](http://www.mathworks.com/products/demos/image/cross_correlation/imreg.html)

Wikipedia calls this "[phase correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_correlation)" and also describes [making it scale- and rotation-invariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration#Spatial_vs._frequency_domain_methods):

> The method can be extended to determine rotation and scaling differences between two images by first converting the images to log-polar coordinates. Due to properties of the Fourier transform, the rotation and scaling parameters can be determined in a manner invariant to translation.

Answer (score 4):

Colour histogram is good for the same image that has been resized, resampled etc.
If you want to match different people's photos of the same landmark it's trickier - look at haar classifiers.  Opencv is a great free library for image processing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the algorithm behind it, but [Microsoft Live Image Search](http://www.live.com/?scope=images) just [added](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/12/find-similar-images-using-live-search.html) this capability.  Picasa also has the ability to identify faces in images, and groups faces that look similar.  Most of the time, it's the same person.

Some machine learning technology like a support vector machine, neural network, naive Bayes classifier or Bayesian network would be best at this type of problem.  I've written one each of the first three to classify handwritten digits, which is essentially image pattern recognition.

Answer (score 0):

resize the image to a 1x1 pixle... if they are exact, there is a small probability they are the same picture...
now resize it to a 2x2 pixle image,  if all 4 pixles are exact, there is a larger probability they are exact...
then 3x3, if all 9 pixles are exact... good chance etc.
then 4x4, if all 16 pixles are exact,... better chance.

etc...

doing it this way, you can make efficiency improvments... if the 1x1 pixel grid is off by a lot,  why bother checking 2x2 grid? etc.

Comment: This won't work in cases where one image has been adjusted slightly, so that it is slightly darker or more saturated, or has been cropped a small amount.  You also have to take into account that resampling is a costly affair, especially when using bicubic interpolation on large images.

Comment: Certainly the first step would be to reduce the original image to a minimal size. There is no need for a "tree on a hill" image to be 10gb to distinguish it from a "flower on a mound" image.

Answer (score 0):

There is [DPEG](http://www.gotdupes.com/index.cfm?page=3495&pagename=d%60peg%21), **"The" Duplicate Media Manager**, but its code is not open. It's a very old tool - I remember using it in 2003.

Comment: Why the two downvotes? The user was asking for a command line tool, not a programming solution.

Comment: @pts: the link wasn't broken for me; it redirected to the current link. I've updated the answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of images, a color histogram could be used to get rough closeness of images before doing a full image comparison of each image against each other one (i.e. O(n^2)).

Answer (score -1):

You could use diff to see if they are REALLY different.. I guess it will remove lots of useless comparison. Then, for the algorithm, I would use a probabilistic approach.. what are the chances that they look the same.. I'd based that on the amount of rgb in each pixel. You could also find some other metrics such as luminosity and stuff like that.