# Image comparison algorithm

Tags: c#

Can anyone suggest an algorithm for image comparison?

Comment: Compare what exactly? Pixels? Metadata? How do you want the results? What will you be using it for?

Comment: Have a read of this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819124/image-comparison-algorithm

Comment: And this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336067/detecting-if-two-images-are-visually-identical

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare the image itself, I can recommend well-established comparison metrics like [Peak signal-to-noise ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_signal-to-noise_ratio) (which is very widely used), or perhaps the [Structural Similarity Index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSIM) (which aims to more closely model the kind of difference that the human eye notices). I would recommend re-using existing implementations, as the large summations these algorithms require are difficult to get right (in short, use BigInteger instead of long or double accumulators).

Also, note that two images may encode the same image using different colour-spaces, so you probably want to ensure both images are transformed to use the same colour-space before comparing them. Of course, if the image is shifted or otherwise modified, you'll need to use some form of feature recognition - see the [Image comparison algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819124/image-comparison-algorithm) post w69rdy referred to.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool compare(unsigned char* f, size_t fs, unsigned char* s, size_t ss)
{
    if (fs != ss)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (register int i=0; i < fs; i++) if (((f+i)*) != ((s+i)*))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```